# sending email from gmail account on XAMPP/Sendmail

Tags: php, gmail, xampp, sendmail.exe

I know this has been done to death on here, but most questions are old, and the responses aren't working this end, so I'm afraid it's a slight repeat.

All I'm trying to do is use XAMPP to send external email via a mail() function in php. When set up on a remote server this is all fine. Change to a local XAMPP server, and nadda.

I've tried several tutorials etc and nothing has worked. My current php.ini, sendmail.ini and my sendmail debug.log are below. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Port numbers seem to conflict in other answers, with 25, 465 and 587 listed. Could this be it?

Thanks in advance

```
13/12/03 10:02:24 ** --- MESSAGE BEGIN ---
13/12/03 10:02:24 ** To: *********@gmail.com
13/12/03 10:02:24 ** Subject: Information Request
13/12/03 10:02:24 ** enter your email address
13/12/03 10:02:24 ** 
13/12/03 10:02:24 ** message here
13/12/03 10:02:24 ** --- MESSAGE END ---
13/12/03 10:02:26 ** Connecting to smtp.gmail.com:587
13/12/03 10:02:26 ** Connected.
13/12/03 10:02:26 << 220 mx.google.com ESMTP o9sm3899245wib.10 - gsmtp<EOL>
13/12/03 10:02:26 >> EHLO Desktop<EOL>
13/12/03 10:02:26 << 250-mx.google.com at your service, [82.22.12.96]<EOL>250-SIZE 35882577<EOL>250-8BITMIME<EOL>250-STARTTLS<EOL>250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES<EOL>250 CHUNKING<EOL>
13/12/03 10:02:26 ** Authenticating as adelejarcher@gmail.com
13/12/03 10:02:26 >> STARTTLS<EOL>
13/12/03 10:02:26 << 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS<EOL>
13/12/03 10:02:26 >> QUIT<EOL>
13/12/03 10:02:26 <<  5  1R¬2˜ƒdkU Kê²/Úbš‚!p·Ê1”U‹“â^      ÿ   #     z0‚v0‚^ :ä^nìó0
    *†H†÷
 0I10   UUS10U

Google Inc1%0#UGoogle Internet Authority G20
130910075447Z
140910075447Z0h10   UUS10U
California10U
Mountain View10U

Google Inc10Usmtp.gmail.com0‚"0
    *†H†÷
 ‚ 0‚
‚ ©0 ÚÖÖ×Ì®TË¥Ÿ.Jå‚ð·›’
QSÙ^ú{pî¯69~0!ã…°vFH;ARDñãRWAé«{Î»?‘CjÏ)öž3s’~´«WšUm› VäVË—e;¾õðÄ7òù’–c¤bœZßæ’%•Ò¨Ýf'v?P>_ˆ,¨ÌihB?’Ÿs2Ç6>á?ßYCI¨|   ±^2òš¿D…Ÿ$X3~˜ð$Øqõÿ®¢VñöÓ [§º«ÇTÕN–æî¾ÞÖmbc0¿™¢²‘öŸ•Ó½'3xÙ‘<Vpú¥õã%ãÂÿy})´†d¶Ô‚µéâ™ÁJ0½[ £‚A0‚=0U%0++0U0‚smtp.gmail.com0h+\0Z0++0†http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crt0++0†http://clients1.google.com/ocsp0UCMe¸ˆÌ×vø:†)Æð&º0Uÿ0 0U#0€JÝ¼öhµvõ¶»bºZ/0U 00
+Öy00U)0'0% # !†http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crl0
    *†H†÷
 ‚  Þ}@µ†¼-
FÅìY§y¼_x¤_ƒYƒDZš§®×a”àbÑyC¤neï}F–<“y"LÞ¢ûsÍ¨‰S3åK “ÿ)HÚD¨ÿB¦ßŠÀçðüà–¿Õ$<qàqTÐYN`íR±n…ùÿÐ™9™'ýå`²;Ög®ºÞÎìopYWV˜låt²ë’äÎ$×ŠD~1Œ"¡¿p0?Joª ó«Gè®¡˜Q9»X.+(¶ÇÓË<ƒ.¹Ëñ"h–(J«>¯m®Ë¶Æh(,WýàÝ`T•îi•å
pN­mé!óc×ÃaÂeüÐza+î‹!Tåö 0‚0‚ì :i0
    *†H†÷
 0B10   UUS10U

GeoTrust Inc.10UGeoTrust Global CA0
130405151555Z
150404151555Z0I10   UUS10U

Google Inc1%0#UGoogle Internet Authority G2
13/12/03 10:02:26 << 0‚"0<CR>   *†H†÷<CR> ‚ 0‚
‚ œ*w\ØP‘:£‚àØPH¼‰?ñpˆF~àÅñ‰Î!îZþa
·2D‰ tSOU¤Î‚b•îëY_Æá€Ä^”?¼[H8ôS÷$æû‘éÄÏôS
ôJüŸTÞ}¾ ko‡ÀÐP(0@ÚsQlÿ:<§7Ž½Kë}$Þæùü1qû”Õ`ó.J¯BÒËêÄj²ÌSÝK‹ÈaÍ¨>c+„5ie„ÈÅF"øS•¾ã€JÆ*ìº— Ç9™ ðaz•%ŒNRuâ¶íÊüÎ"j³NÏF——~À±Þ{¯E3Ïº>q·Þô%%Â
5‰ûy‰7Å¯Žri £û0ø0U#0€Àz˜h‰û«d}ª}e¸ÊÌN0UJÝ¼öhµvõ¶»bºZ/0Uÿ0ÿ 0Uÿ0:U3010/ - +†)http://crl.geotrust.com/crls/gtglobal.crl0=+10/0-+0†!http://gtglobal-ocsp.geotrust.com0U 00
+Öy0
    *†H†÷
 ‚ 6×€'­*›8w³# uX»±~ƒBºrÚØŽ6—àð•;7ýBXþ"Èk½8^Ñ;%në^gvF@ÚÈx
í•fÚŽ†o€¡ºV2•†ÜÜjÊŒ[ö¿Ìo…XÃhQÍýÈ÷y=™5ðV£½àYíOD  £ž8zöFÑO¾Ð@üUþ^<ÚV½–Q{oW*Û¢ª–ÜŒtÂ•¾ðn•ÿð<¬²ÌsûèÆðû3³•;ãÂËhXsÛ¨$b;5
©3½x.Lx]P:Ôî Èp8Ü²ùgú‡@]aÀQkƒkÍ:Êá§xüÊÚ”Ð,=~yÈ P $T3q 0‚}0‚æ »æ0
    *†H†÷
 0N10   UUS10U
Equifax1-0+U$Equifax Secure Certificate Authority0
020521040000Z
180821040000Z0B10   UUS10U

GeoTrust Inc.10UGeoTrust Global CA0‚"0
    *†H†÷
 ‚ 0‚
‚ ÚÌc0ýô#V~[ß<l8äq·x‘Ô¼¡ØLø¨C¶éM!ˆÚX/f9)½x‹8è·j~q¤æÄ`¦°ï€ä‰(ž%Öíƒó­¦‘Ç˜ÉB5­˜F’.OÊñ‡CÁ•W-Pï‰-€zW­òî_kÒ ¹ø5ÙÀF£{rÈ‘¿ÉU+ÍÐ—>œ&dÌßÎƒqÊNæÔÕ{©ÍUÞÈìÒ^8Så\OŒ-þP#6üfæËŽ¤9 ·•9‘þ8.ÑšöM>o¯,`9âú6S9Ô^&+Û=¨½2ë(Rqå«3=á8»6„bœyê0ô_À+èqkäù £ð0í0U#0€Hæhù+Ò²•×GØ# O3˜ŸÔ0UÀz˜h‰û«d}ª}e¸ÊÌN0Uÿ0ÿ0Uÿ0:U3010/ - +†)http://crl.geotrust.com/crls/secureca.crl0NU G0E0CU  0;09+-https://www.geotrust.com/resources/repository0
    *†H†÷
  vánNK†0²ÏðÇÇq~fîÂíÔ;ÿððÈNÖC8°¹0}ÐUƒ¢jË6œèHf£m¸ÔGþ‹Z\sü®Ù28«—4ª–Òë£I¶»å‘ïƒ6ëVoÊÚ¼scä{>"Ë=í_8tœãPN¡¯˜îaò„?    
13/12/03 10:02:26 <<  F
13/12/03 10:02:26 ** Disconnected.
13/12/03 10:02:26 ** Disconnecting from smtp.gmail.com:587
13/12/03 10:02:26 ** Disconnected.
13/12/03 10:02:26 ** Disconnected.
13/12/03 10:02:26 ** Connection Closed Gracefully.
```

php.ini here

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = *********@gmail.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
mail.log = "C:\xampp\apache\logs\php_mail.log"
```

sendmail.ini here:

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=*******@gmail.com
auth_password=********
force_sender=********@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

on your php.ini file,change the smtp from smtp.gmail.com to localhost

```
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
;http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
```

I think that should solve it

Answer (score -1):

```
Gmail SMTP server address: smtp.gmail.com
Gmail SMTP user name: Your full Gmail address (e.g. example@gmail.com)
Gmail SMTP password: Your Gmail password
Gmail SMTP port: 465
Gmail SMTP TLS/SSL required: yes
```

Check with above information.